# Is there a workaround to the glitched level in Portal: First Slice?

Tags: portal

I can't seem to complete Level 11 in Portal: First Slice. It seems to be glitched up. I can shoot portals, but cant go through them.

What's going on? Is there a fix or workaround for this?

Comment: A picture would be helpful to illustrate what you are talking about.  Without more detail, I can't really even tell you if your difficulty is an actual glitch or just a misunderstanding of the level's solution.

Comment: Also, that isn't really a question or at least it's unclear what you are asking. Could you perhaps rephrase is as a clear question? Something like, how do I get past this level or is there a fix for this?